# Cannot find the paint color on Ford Focus 2003

Tags: ford, paint, focus, chassis-paint

I'm searching for paint to paint my replacement bumper on my European 2003 Ford Focus 4 door Berline and I cannot find the paint code in any list online
This is the plaque that was under the hood (was removed when replacing the front bumper assembly)
If anyone knows what blue paint to buy for this car that would be great!

[image: Ford focus engine bay plaque]

Comment: Have you checked the stickers on the driver's side door jam?
https://www.blueovaltech.com/tech/decode.php

Comment: There was no such sticker on my car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the Ford dealership and they ran my VIN number to tell me the color was "Bleu de chine"

But since I could not find this color anywhere online I searched some more and found that it was the same as Ink Blue, Ford Paint code 3CYC and I just ordered the paint online.

Thank you all for your suggestions

Answer (score 4):

I can't read the tag very well but I assumed it was K2 which should be this car's color(Smokestone). If thats wrong theres only a few other blue options (Amparo Blue:G, Blue Print:T, Capri Blue:L, Imperial Blue:Q, Ink Blue: I, Metropolis Blue:A, State Blue:H)

[image: Smokestone Blue]
[image: Ford Color Code Chart Europe]
[image]

Sources: https://www.remarkpen.com/files/documents/colorCode/fordeurope.pdf

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

It should be the last but one box on the left column:

[image]

Looks like T2 to me?

Ford colour codes are a nightmare to find in the lists - as the same code can mean different things from year to year and model to model. If you give that code and your model/year info to a paint supplier they should be able to figure it out though. Failing that you can always contact Ford and give them the VIN (the 17 digit sequence in the second box on the right column) and they can give you the info.